# How does tf.GradientTape record operations inside the with statement?

Tags: python, tensorflow, gradient

I don't understand how tf.GradientTape record operations like `y=x**2` inside the "with" statement (following operations).

```
x = tf.Variable(3.0)

with tf.GradientTape() as tape:
  y = x**2
```

What Python syntax can be used to achieve this behavior?

Comment: The key here is that `x` is a `tf.Variable` object, and has a `__pow__()` method to override exponentiation. Thus `x` knows when it is accessed (i.e. this or another of its operation methods is called) and can record the operation to the tape.

Comment: is this your guess?

Answer (score 1):

**EDIT**:

As per the GitHub source code, [GradientTape](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/v2.11.0/tensorflow/python/eager/backprop.py#L751-L1391),
At `Line 897`:

```py
 @tf_contextlib.contextmanager
  def _ensure_recording(self):
    """Ensures that this tape is recording."""
    if not self._recording:
      try:
        self._push_tape()
        yield
      finally:
        self._pop_tape()
    else:
      yield
```

If you don't know, `contextmanager` triggers whenever `with` keyword is used. It tells us that it starts keeping track of tape.

`self._pop_tape()` is in `Line 891`:

```py
def _pop_tape(self):
    if not self._recording:
      raise ValueError("Tape is not recording.")
    tape.pop_tape(self._tape)
    self._recording = False
```

`self._push_tape()` is in `Line 878`:

```py
def _push_tape(self):
    """Pushes a new tape onto the tape stack."""
    if self._recording:
      raise ValueError("Tape is still recording, This can happen if you try to "
                       "re-enter an already-active tape.")
    if self._tape is None:
      self._tape = tape.push_new_tape(
          persistent=self._persistent,
          watch_accessed_variables=self._watch_accessed_variables)
    else:
      tape.push_tape(self._tape)
    self._recording = True
```

Here, you can notice `tape.push_new_tape` is being accessed here which can be found in this [source code](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/v2.11.0/tensorflow/python/eager/tape.py) at `Line 43`:

```py
def push_new_tape(persistent=False, watch_accessed_variables=True):
  """Pushes a new tape onto the tape stack."""
  tape = pywrap_tfe.TFE_Py_TapeSetNew(persistent, watch_accessed_variables)
  return Tape(tape)
```

In this you can see the `Tape` class just above at `Line 31`.

```py
class Tape(object):
  """Represents a gradient propagation trace."""

  __slots__ = ["_tape"]

  def __init__(self, tape):
    self._tape = tape

  def watched_variables(self):
    return pywrap_tfe.TFE_Py_TapeWatchedVariables(self._tape)
```

Also, I tried to track `pywrap_tfe.TFE_Py_TapeSetNew` but couldn't find it in this [source code of the file](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/v2.11.0/tensorflow/python/pywrap_tfe.py).

**Original Answer**:

The documentation of [GradientTape](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/GradientTape) states:

> By default GradientTape will automatically watch any trainable variables that are accessed inside the context. If you want fine grained control over which variables are watched you can disable automatic tracking by passing watch_accessed_variables=False to the tape constructor

With the following code:

```py
x = tf.Variable(2.0)
w = tf.Variable(5.0)
with tf.GradientTape(
    watch_accessed_variables=False, persistent=True) as tape:
  tape.watch(x)
  y = x ** 2  # Gradients will be available for `x`.
  z = w ** 3  # No gradients will be available as `w` isn't being watched.
dy_dx = tape.gradient(y, x)

print(dy_dx)
>>> tf.Tensor(4.0, shape=(), dtype=float32)

# No gradients will be available as `w` isn't being watched.
dz_dw = tape.gradient(z, w)

print(dz_dw)
>>> None
```

Comment: What I'm really curious about is how the watch method records y and z from x. not the result.